# How to Make Water Rooster Tail

Tags: rendering, particles

First time poster here. I have a rendering project I’d like to give a water spray effect to, such as that seen behind high-speed boats under power (see reference images or see [here](https://youtu.be/LnZSKGGqyOo?feature=shared) about 3 min in). I’m trying to think of how to achieve this effect in Blender without melting my video card.

My first thought was to use a sprite particle emitter and cast out a lot of particles influenced by gravity to get the parabolic shape of the spray. This is most similar to reality, but I think that’s going to take a ton of particles, unless I devise a way to make smoke effects fill in the majority of the spray.

Is there some more elegant way to do this that anyone might know of? Just looking for suggestions before I go barking up the wrong tree.

For now I’m just going to do a static image, so this doesn’t need to be animated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]